# Why am I getting a "Nullable object must have a value" exception when I'm using Condition?

Tags: automapper

I'm getting a "Nullable object must have a value" in the example code below.  Why do I need the following fix to make this work:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.ShirtColor,
           dest => dest.MapFrom(src => src.ShirtColor != null
                                       ? new OptionSetValue((int) src.ShirtColor)
                                       : null))
```

```cs
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PersonA, PersonB>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))

    // Condition to avoid overwriting existing data!!!
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ShirtColor,
               dest => dest.Condition(src => src.ShirtColor != null))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ShirtColor,
               dest => dest.MapFrom(
                   src => new OptionSetValue((int)src.ShirtColor)))
    // Fix that should not be needed due to condition:
    //.ForMember(dest => dest.ShirtColor,
    //           dest => dest.MapFrom(
    //               src => src.ShirtColor != null
    //                      ? new OptionSetValue((int) src.ShirtColor)
    //                      : null));


PersonA source = new PersonA();
source.FirstName = "Thomas";
source.LastName = "Jefferson";
source.ShirtColor = null;  // nullable int

PersonB destination = new PersonB();
destination.FirstName = "Thomas";
destination.LastName = "Jefferson";
destination.ShirtColor = new OptionSetValue(4);

// Results in: "Nullable object must have a value" despite the fact that
// condition should have been met!
Mapper.Map<PersonA, PersonB>(source, destination);

Debug.Assert(destination.ShirtColor != null);
Console.WriteLine("Our existing data was not overwritten!!");

Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to exit");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is how OptionSet is defined:
    public class OptionSetValue
    {
        public OptionSetValue(){}

```cs
    public OptionSetValue(int value)
    {
        Number = value;
    }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use `PreCondition` instead of `Condition`..

So change your

```cs
//Condition to avoid overwriting existing data!!!
.ForMember(dest => dest.ShirtColor, dest => dest.Condition(src => src.ShirtColor != null))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ShirtColor, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => new OptionSetValue((int)src.ShirtColor)))
```

to

```cs
//Condition to avoid overwriting existing data!!!
.ForMember(dest => dest.ShirtColor, dest => dest.PreCondition(src => src.ShirtColor != null))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ShirtColor, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => new OptionSetValue((int)src.ShirtColor)))
```

Comment: Exaclty! So simple, yet I had to dig quite a long time for this solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```cs
.ForMember(dest => dest.ShirtColor,
           dest => dest.Condition(src => src.ShirtColor != null))
```

to

```cs
.ForMember(dest => dest.ShirtColor,
           opt => opt.Condition(src => !src.IsSourceValueNull))
```

Note that you also don't need the following as they are mapped by convention:

```cs
.ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
.ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
```

---

**UPDATE - 2**

The problem is related to the fact that the condition and mapping haven't been combined. I've created a simple extension method to allow for it.

Here is a test to demonstrate it

**Classes**

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonA : Person
{
    public int? ShirtColor { get; set; }
}

public class PersonB : Person
{
    public OptionSetValue ShirtColor { get; set; }
}

public class OptionSetValue
{
    public int OptionSet { get; set; }
}
```

**MappingConfiguration**

```cs
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<PersonA, PersonB>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.ShirtColor,
                         opt => opt.ConditionallyMapFrom(
                             src => new OptionSetValue
                                 {
                                     OptionSet = src.ShirtColor.Value
                                 },
                             src => src.ShirtColor.HasValue));
    }
}

public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static void ConditionallyMapFrom<TSource, TMember>(
                         this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource> expression,
                         Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> sourceMember,
                         Func<TSource, bool> condition)
    {
        expression.Condition(condition);
        expression.MapFrom(sourceMember);
    }
}
```

**UnitTests**

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class MappingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void AutoMapper_Configuration_IsValid()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }

    [Test]
    public void AutoMapper_ClientMapping_IsValid()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var source = new PersonA
            {
                FirstName = "FirstA",
                LastName = "LastA",
                ShirtColor = null
            };

        var destination = new PersonB
            {
                FirstName = "FirstB",
                LastName = "LastB"
            };

        destination = Mapper.Map(source, destination);

        Assert.That(destination, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(destination.FirstName, Is.EqualTo("FirstA"));
        Assert.That(destination.LastName, Is.EqualTo("LastA"));
        Assert.That(destination.ShirtColor, Is.Null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this didn't fix it.  Strings don't seem to exhibit the problem.  If you changed ShirtColor to a nullable int (int?) in one class and a class in the other (OptionSetValue - class with one int property), you will see that the problem still exists.  This has something to do with the target property being a class, which is the only time I see it.

Comment: OK cool, thanks for the update - I've now been able to recreate it. Will see if I can find a workaround.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your updated criteria - or rather, new knowledge of your previous criteria :)

Comment: I appreciate your help, but that didn't work for me.  Even if it did work, the commented fix above would be more to my liking since it is easier to discover.  I really do believe that this is a bug in AutoMapper.  If you actually put my commented fix in, the data will NOT be overwritten.  My guess is that the condition is evaluated AFTER the mapping call and NOT applied if the condition is not met.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work - are you able to elaborate (ie, what have I missed in the unit tests)? A "proper" solution would be the ability to chain the commands together (eg `opt.MapFrom(...).Condition(...)`), but as that's not currently available I use the provided extension method. You might be able create your own to achieve what you want (eg, `expression.Condition(condition); return expression;`).

Answer (score 2):

Just cast it to a *nullable* `int`:

```
.ForMember((destination)         => destination.ShirtColor,
           (memberConfiguration) => memberConfiguration.MapFrom((source) => (int?)source.ShirtColor))
```

Comment: This is very good idea - I created extension method for that: https://gist.github.com/MaLiN2223/990e42299dc7790c02f91179c9715c96 (second Define)

Answer (score 0):

Might help someone.

I was getting this exception when there was a code trying to resolve an enumeration for a invalid value inside automapper.

I also feel the possible scenario for others could be you are creating an exception based on your logic inside automapper.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Employee, Domain.Entities.Employee>().
      .ForMember(dest => dest.EmployeeType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>(EmployeeTypeEnum)src.EmployeeTypeId))  
  // if the EmployeeTypeId has an invalid value which does not match the enum values we get exception
```